# Путаются сертификаты между доменами в NGINX, что делать?

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl

В последнее время происходят непонятки с SSL и NGINX: происходит путаница сертификатов между собой. На сервере много доменов (500+). Если раньше показывало, что сертификат не от того домена (допустим, зайдя на test.ru выдавало, что сертификат принадлежит test1.ru) и методом удаления сертификата test1.ru всё решалось, то сейчас всё зашло совсем в тупик, выдает: "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения." без каких-либо дополнительных сведений.

Синтаксис нормальный (nginx -t), визуально тоже пробегаюсь - всё ок (хотя могу что-то упустить с таким объемом).

Конфиг для домена:

```
    server {
server_name s1.com www.s1.com;
listen 1.1.1.1;
listen 1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
set $root_path /var/www/red/data/www/s1.com;
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
root $root_path;
access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/red isp;
access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/s1.access.log ;
error_page 404 = @fallback;
}
location / {
proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:81;
proxy_redirect 1.1.1.1:81 /;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:81;
proxy_redirect 1.1.1.1:81 /;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location @fallback {
proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:81;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
limit_conn red 200;
ssl_certificate /var/www/httpd-cert/s1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/httpd-cert/s1.key;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: я дополнил ответ.

Comment: IP адреса в `listen` это плохой признак. Вы точно используете их во всех блоках `server`?

Answer (score 2):

так проверяйте: может быть, у вас, действительно, файлы с сертификатами перепутаны.

домен(ы), для которых выпущен сертификат, записаны в поле *subject* сертификата, в виде `CN=имя.домена` и в *X509v3 Subject Alternative Name* в виде `DNS:имя.домена`.

```
$ cat /путь/к/файлу | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -E '(DNS|Subj.*CN)'
        Subject: CN=mail.domain.ru
                DNS:imap.domain.ru, DNS:mail.domain.ru, DNS:smtp.domain.ru
```

для проверки же информации в сертификате, который отдаёт http-сервер, команду `cat /путь/к/файлу` можно заменить на конструкцию:

```
$ :| openssl s_client -showcerts -servername имя.домена -connect имя.домена:443 2>/dev/null
```

к примеру, для yandex.ru (вывод я разбил на строки для удобства просмотра):

```
$ :| openssl s_client -showcerts -servername yandex.ru -connect yandex.ru:443 \
 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -E '(DNS|Subj.*CN)'
Subject: C=RU, O=Yandex LLC, OU=ITO, L=Moscow, ST=Russia, CN=yandex.ru
        DNS:xmlsearch.yandex.ua, DNS:yandex.net, DNS:images.yandex.ru,
DNS:xmlsearch.yandex.com.tr, DNS:family.yandex.com.tr,
DNS:people.yandex.kz, DNS:m.yandex.kz, DNS:xmlsearch.yandex.com,
DNS:play.yandex.com.tr, DNS:gorsel.yandex.com.tr, DNS:images.yandex.com,
DNS:aile.yandex.com.tr, DNS:m.yandex.ua, DNS:game.yandex.com.tr,
DNS:video.yandex.ua, DNS:yandex.com.tr, DNS:video.yandex.ru,
DNS:yandex.kz, DNS:video.yandex.com.tr, DNS:m.yandex.ru,
DNS:www.yandex.ua, DNS:www.yandex.kz, DNS:games.yandex.com.tr,
DNS:m.yandex.com, DNS:yandex.ua, DNS:yandex.by, DNS:images.yandex.ua,
DNS:xmlsearch.yandex.kz, DNS:m.yandex.by, DNS:www.yandex.ru,
DNS:video.yandex.com, DNS:video.yandex.by, DNS:oyun.yandex.com.tr,
DNS:xmlsearch.yandex.ru, DNS:people.yandex.by, DNS:people.yandex.ru,
DNS:images.yandex.kz, DNS:www.yandex.com, DNS:yandex.com,
DNS:m.yandex.com.tr, DNS:images.yandex.com.tr, DNS:www.yandex.com.tr,
DNS:xmlsearch.yandex.by, DNS:people.yandex.ua, DNS:yandex.ru,
DNS:www.yandex.by, DNS:video.yandex.kz, DNS:images.yandex.by
```

---

> "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения."

по этому поводу надо смотреть логи http-сервера.

а со стороны клиента как первоначальное средство диагностики можно использовать, например, *wget*:

```
$ wget -S --spider https://имя.домена
```

---

### по поводу предоставленной конфигурации

вызывает недоумение вот этот фрагмент:

```
listen 1.1.1.1;
listen 1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
```

у вас, получается, одна секция и под порт 80, и под порт 443:

> [Если указан только адрес, то используется порт 80.](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

т.е., на 80-м порту, у вас, насколько я понимаю, происходит попытка ответить клиенту на https-запрос, а не на http.

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию, но сертификаты прописаны правильно. Прикрепил конфиг к вопросу. Проблема именно в том, что прописываю любой сертификат к домену - он не работает, будто строчки, подключающие ssl не читаются nginx.

Comment: может быть, «срабатывает» другая секция `server`.

Comment: да, возможно, но как определить какая секция считывается? ибо синтаксис, если верить nginx -t, верный

Comment: как обычно: убираете все описания, кроме одного сайта, проверяете, дальше методом половинного деления: возвращаете половину описаний, проверяете. и т.д.